# open Internet Explorer in Java without specifying the path

Tags: java, internet-explorer, runtime.exec

I want to open Internet Explorer dynamically with a new session, without knowing the exact path. I tried to open Internet Explorer from Java, using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("iexplore.exe -noframemerging http://google.com/");
```

But since `iexplore.exe` is not defined in a system variable, it was not able to find the location.

Please suggest me some way to move forward.

Comment: *"Please suggest me some way to move forward."*  [`Desktop.browse(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse-java.net.URI-)

Answer (score 3):

The follwoing will load google into your default browser on Windows...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start http://google.com/");
```

Comment: Thanks a Ton. You save my time. It worked absolutely fine..
Just one query, what is the use of "/c" ?

Comment: Your welcome! The /c parameter tells cmd to run the command that follows - in this case start http://google.com/. If you type cmd /? in a command prompt you'll see a ton of info on cmd

Answer (score 0):

```
Process browser = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe \"http://www.google.com\"");
```